# QGIS 3 r.texture no output

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, texture

I cannot solve the mystery of no outputs in any case and in any experiment I have done with all kinds of parameters in the latest QGIS 3.2.3 Bonn and GRASS 7. r.texture does not provide any output. Not in temp folders, not in user defined folders. I have not used this function before to know the details however.

Anyone else having the same issue? Any workarounds?

The last time I run it, I got the following LOG output:

> Processing algorithm… Algorithm 'r.texture' starting… Input
>   parameters: { '-a' : False, '-s' : False,
>   'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' :
>   None, 'distance' : 1, 'input' :
>   'C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Temp/processing_b31ae406d97346319858b8acfa3fe9ea/d40ba480206c44e1855a50ce4442b154/output.tif',
>   'method' : [0], 'output' : 'C:\Users\...\textures', 'size' : 3 }
>
> g.proj -c proj4="+proj=utm +zone=...+datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
>   r.external
>   input="C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_b31ae406d97346319858b8acfa3fe9ea\d40ba480206c44e1855a50ce4442b154\output.tif"
>   band=1 output="rast_5bc7529c4be7121" --overwrite -o g.region
>   n=...s=...e=...w=...
>   res=0.08917000000001485 r.texture input=rast_5bc7529c4be7121
>   method="asm" size=3 distance=1
>   output=output0721b2f6bc07456a8304b894c5bcf6e4 --overwrite for r in
>   $(g.list type=rast pattern='output0721b2f6bc07456a8304b894c5bcf6e4*');
>   do r.out.gdal -m -t input=${r}
>   output=C:\Users...\textures/${r}.tif
>   --overwrite -c createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" done Starting GRASS GIS...
>
> WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows
>
> Executing
>   
>   ...
>
> C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>chcp 1252 1>NUL
>
> C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>g.proj -c proj4="+proj=utm +zone=...+datum=WGS84
>   +units=m +no_defs"
>
> Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have
>   multiple mapsets `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the
>   region from the default
>
> Projection information updated
>
> C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>r.external
>   input="C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_b31ae406d97346319858b8acfa3fe9ea\d40ba480206c44e1855a50ce4442b154\output.tif"
>   band=1 output="rast_5bc7529c4be7121" --overwrite -o
>
> Over-riding projection check
>
> Reading band 1 of 1...
>
> r.external complete. Link to raster map 
>   created.
>
> C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>g.region n=...s=...
>   e=...w=... res=0.08917000000001485
>
> C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>r.texture input=rast_5bc7529c4be7121 method="asm"
>   size=3 distance=1 output=output0721b2f6bc07456a8304b894c5bcf6e4
>   --overwrite
>
> Reading raster map...
>
> Calculating Angular Second Moment...
>
> 2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
>
> r was unexpected at this time.
>
> C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>for r in $(g.list type=rast
>   pattern='output0721b2f6bc07456a8304b894c5bcf6e4*'); do
>
> Execution of
>   
>   finished.
>
> Cleaning up temporary files...
>
> Press any key to continue . . .
>
> Starting GRASS GIS...
>
> WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows
>
> Executing
>   
>   ...
>
> C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>chcp 1252 1>NUL
>
> r was unexpected at this time.
>
> C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>for r in $(g.list type=rast
>   pattern='output0721b2f6bc07456a8304b894c5bcf6e4*'); do
>
> Execution of
>   
>   finished.
>
> Cleaning up temporary files...
>
> Press any key to continue . . .
>
> Execution completed in 7.08 seconds Results: {'output':
>   'C:\Users\...\textures'}
>
> Loading resulting layers Algorithm 'r.texture' finished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have opened a bug report, as it works under QGIS 2.18
So if it is a bug, it needs patience and the workaround is the older QGIS version.

Answer (score 0):

caveat: I don't use Windows, so I'm not in a position to check this.

This snippet from the log looks suspicious - it appears twice

```
r was unexpected at this time.

C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>for r in $(g.list type=rast pattern='output0721b2f6bc07456a8304b894c5bcf6e4*'); do
```

I think this may be caused by running a bash-style script under Windows. I believe the syntax to iterate over a list of files is very [slightly different under windows](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) than it is on Linux/Mac.

If this is not something you wrote, it might be worthing [raising this as a tracker](https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/issues) (if it hasn't been reported already).

Comment: Thanks for the input Steven, I have opened a bug report, as it works under QGIS 2.18

Comment: What about running it inside GRASS in the same installation? Have you tried that?